# Написать SQL-запрос, удовлетворяющий требованиям

Tags: sql, oracle

Как написать 3 запроса, чтобы каждый вывел бы:

1. CLIENT, для которых значения FILTERVALUE различны.
2. CLIENT, для которых значение FILTERVALUE заполнено.
3. CLIENT, для которых значение FILTERVALUE не заполнено.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `1` - вы ходите найти одинаковые CLIENT, имеющие разные FILTERVALUE? `2` и `3` - у вас FILTERVALUE может null принимать?

Comment: да я хочу получить CLIENT имеющие разные FILTERVALUE. то есть данных может быть много. скрин приведен для примера. FILTERVALUE  - мб null

Comment: А если для клиента есть несколько записей, и в некоторых `FILTERVALUE` заполнено, а в некоторых нет - это куда, в 2 или 3? А в 1 это имеется в виду "_все_ различны"? Ну вы сделайте группировку по клиенту, а дальше считайте... а вот что именно считать - зависит от точной формулировки вопроса. Ну а дальше `JOIN` того, что посчитали, к вашей таблице.

Comment: в некоторых FILTERVALUE заполнено, а в некоторых нет это все в 1. 2 и 3 запрос отдельно рассматривается.

Comment: SELECT CLIENT FROM FILTERTCPSETTINGS GROUP BY CLIENT HAVING COUNT(CLIENT) > 1;                   я написал такое но чувствую что то не то. как тут учитывтаь FILTERVALUE ?

Comment: `SELECT CLIENT FROM FILTERTCPSETTINGS GROUP BY CLIENT HAVING COUNT(distinct filtervalue) > 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример:

```
insert ALL 
  into table1 (client,filtervalue) values (1,'192.168.0.1')
  into table1 (client,filtervalue) values (1,'192.168.0.2')
  into table1 (client,filtervalue) values (2,'192.168.0.1')
  into table1 (client,filtervalue) values (3,'192.168.0.1')
  into table1 (client,filtervalue) values (1,null)
  into table1 (client,filtervalue) values (3,null)
  select 1 from dual
  ;
select client
  ,case when max(filtervalue)<>min(filtervalue) then 'V' end p1
  ,max(case when filtervalue is not null then 'V' end )p2
  ,max(case when filtervalue is  null then 'V' end )p3
from table1
group by client
order by client
```

Результат:

| CLIENT | P1 | P2 | P3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | V | V | V |
| 2 | null | V | null |
| 3 | null | V | V |

P1 - различные значения
P2 - заполнено
P3 - не заполнено